# How do I open a file as a URL?

Tags: files

I'm running Kubuntu21.10.  I've downloaded a music-playing file named **128.m3u**. I can get it to play music from a browser, e.g., Firefox, by accessing it via "Open File'. How can I turn it into a URL? I've tried things like **file://paul/Downloads/128.m3u**, but I haven't found the right combination.  Another way of describing what I need is a URL that provides the equivalent of the "Open File" command in a browser.

I want to turn it into a URL and not just play it directly because I want to install it as an entry in my music player.  For that I need a URL.

Comment: The file type `m3u` is a playlist. The songs in the playlist may be stored locally or in a remote server. You can try to open this file in a MP3 player. Assuming the file is in your Downloads folder the I guess the correct URL should be `file:///home/paul/Downloads.128.m3u`. Note three /// in the beginning, and starting with `home/`.

Comment: I just tried to open a `m3u` file in Firefox by dragging and dropping it on an open Firefox window. It did not open the file in the browser. It gave me the option to open the file using one of the media player app I have installed in my Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: user68186 has the right answer, but I couldn't figure out how to mark it as such. It also has a typo: it should be "Downloads/128.m3u', not "Downloads.128.m3u".

Comment: I will convert my comments to an answer. And fix the typo. :)

Comment: what music player are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Drag and Drop

You can open a file in Firefox by simply dragging and dropping the file in an open Firefox new tab. Depending on the type of the file, it may or may not open in Firefox. For example, dragging and dropping an m3u file in Firefox shows me this window:

[image]

The file type m3u is a playlist. The songs in the playlist may be stored locally or in a remote server. You can open the m3u file using the default mp3 player app installed in your computer.

## File Open Dialogue

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to get the file open dialogue in Firefox. From there you can navigate to the `Downloads` folder and select the the file `128.m3u`. Once again Firefox can't open this file and shows me the dialogue window pictured above.

## Type out the URL

File URLs are prefixed with `file://`. However you need to specify the full path of the file. Since the full path starts with `/`, the prefix is `file:///`. In your case the file URL is:

```
file:///home/paul/Downloads/128.m3u
```

Note, file and folder names are case sensitive in Ubuntu. Once again Firefox prompts me to open the file in a media player.

Hope this helps

Comment: Only the solution with file:// works in this context, sine I 'm not trying to open the URL in Firefox;I'm providing it to a music-playing program which associates it with an Internet radio station.

Comment: @PaulA. You may try to open the file directly in the music playing program. I can just double click on the m3u file to open it with the program "Videos" without the need to go through Firefox. I can also right click on the m3u file and choose which program you want to open it with in Gnome. Check [this](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/File_Associations/en) and [this](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-cli-tools/kcontrol5/filetypes/index.html) for similar associations in KDE.

Answer (score 0):

## xdg-open

### xdg-open - opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application

Synopsis

xdg-open { file | URL }

xdg-open { --help | --manual | --version }

Use 'man xdg-open' or 'xdg-open --manual' for additional info.

### Two ways to open an mp3 file

#### URL syntax

- xdg-open file:///home/steve/Audio/Carole\ King/One\ Small\ Voice/onesmallvoice.mp3

#### file syntax

- cd ~/Audio/Carole King/One Small Voice
- xdg-open onesmallvoice.mp3

#### Finally

- Both open the mp3 in a new window with the VLC media player
- The tricky part may be escaping blanks in the path to the artists' names, album titles, and song titles.
- Using xdg-open can help make sure that the URL syntax works properly before adding or updating an entry for the title in your application.